# Does Macbook Pro protect itself from heat?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

Mine is a Macbook Pro 15-inch Late-2013.

I read somewhere that the laptop protects itself from damage by shutting itself down when it gets too hot.

My laptop's temperature, currently at its highest is 95ºC.

The Apple website said that it's maximum operating temperature is 35ºC.

I'm using Macs Fan Control, to tell me the temperature.

https://support.apple.com/kb/sp690?locale=en_GB <-- where temperature is stated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

Yes.

**Long answer**

By *Operating Temperature* Apple are **not** referring to the internal temperature of the MacBook Pro. Instead, they are referring to the temperature of the environment in which you're using (i.e. *operating*) the MacBook Pro.

That's not to say you couldn't use your MBP outside on a hot 35ºC day, but you *may* run into problems and, if you do, that's when the System Management Controller (SMC) will kick in to protect your MBP.

By the way, **your MBP temp of 95ºC is perfectly fine.** MBP models *usually* range from about 40ºC (104ºF) to 100ºC (212ºF) depending on whether the CPU is idle or under load. The SMC is designed to monitor a range of sensors and to manage tasks such as fan speeds etc to ensure your MBP is protected from damage by overheating.

If you're interested, you can also refer to the [Intel Mac Temperature Database](https://www.intelmactemp.com/list) to see the various temperature ranges reported by users.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think this is an answer that is beyond what I expected. :)